# Start new section from particular height in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Maybe this question has been asked before, but I didn't find a proper solution.
I have a `UITableView` with a section inside it. Basically what I want to     do is start new section at a particular height of previous section.

Suppose I have 5 row in first section and height of that is 500, my second section I want to start at 250 (half of the previous section).
So is there any way in tableview to do that? Any help regarding this will be appreciated.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: You have to make the first section's height 250. What do you expect would happend when you add the new section in the middle of an existing one? Would you expect it to split in half? Does not make sense at all.

Comment: Yes i want to start in the middle of the previous section ... as i have requirement to show the data on left side and right side.
So i have the tableview and in tableviewcell i have to view left & rightview and using flag i show the left and right view.

Comment: You can't add anything in the middle of the previous section. You can remove cells from the previous section and add them to a new one if you want to split it. Don't understand what left and right got to do with this. You can use rectForRowAtIndexPath to check, which cell is at 250px.

Comment: let me share you the screenshot wait

Comment: Maybe you should use 2 distinct UITableView for that?

Comment: we can do with that but i want to do with single tableview.